# How to handle KeyError(f"Key '{key}' not present") wor2vec with gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, keyerror

I have build a model with gensim library and am trying to get the vector of word that not present in the vocabulary but i have an error, and i want to handle this error with the best i way.
If i can get the vector of word not present in the model that well be perfect.

**The code**

```
model = KeyedVectors.load('nice.model')
token_vector = model.wv['bla bla bla']
```

**Error**

```
  File "/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/WebScarping/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 421, in get_index
    raise KeyError(f"Key '{key}' not present")
KeyError: "Key 'hmed' not present"
```

please help me in resolving the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the token is not present in the model, it can't give you a vector for it.

Your model doesn't have a vector for the (pseudo-)word `'bla bla bla'`, all it can do is report that.

You could avoid the exception by pre-checking whether the token is present, and only requesting it if present:

```py
if token in model.wv:
    token_vector = model.wv[token]
else:
    # whatever your next-best step is when a vector not available
    ...
```

Or, you could catch the exception:

```py
try:
    token_vector = model.wv[token]
except KeyError:
    # whatever your next-best step is when a vector not available
    ...
```

But there's no magic way to create a good vector for an unknown token. You'll have to ignore such words, or make-up some plug stand-in value, or figure some other project-appropriate workaround.

(If you have sufficient training data with varied examples of the token's real usage, you could train a model that includes the token. You could also consider finding or training a word2vec variant model like `FastText`, which can synthesize guess-vectors for unknown tokens based on which substrings they might share with words learned in training – but such vectors may be quite poor in quality.)

Comment: Thanks gojomo, it's good when the token is not present in the model i generate a vector [0 for x in range(0,100)] like [0, 0,0...]

Comment: FWIW, a more compact & efficient way to create a zero-vector that's exactly type-equivalent to the other non-zero word-vectors you'd get from a Gensim model would be `np.zeros(vector_size, type=np.float32)`. But also note: a zero vector may still be misleading/suboptimal, as an assumed value for unknown words, and may cause some vector-to-vector calculations to fail. (You can't take cosine-similarity with the zero-vector.) So often it leads to better results to just pretend unknown words aren't there at all - it's worthwhile to test both ways, if you can.